# firefox scrollHeight vs overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HzeE7/13/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="relative">
  <div id="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#relative {
  position : relative;
  width    : 200px;
  height   : 200px;
  overflow : visible;
}
#absolute {
  position   : absolute;
  width      : 200px;
  height     : 300px;
  background : #eee;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
console.log($("#relative").get(0).scrollHeight);
$("#relative").css({
  "overflow-x" : "hidden",
  "overflow-y" : "scroll"
});
console.log($("#relative").get(0).scrollHeight);
```

It returns "300, 300" in chrome and ie 9, "200, 300" in firefox.

Is there a way to detect "300" without changing overflow?

Comment: What you want to do? Pls explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

No scrollbars = no scrollHeight.

> When an element's content does not generate a vertical scrollbar, then its scrollHeight property is equal to its clientHeight property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight

Comment: dont you want to take just height of child element? $('#relative > div') or just $('#absolute')?

Comment: this is just an example. There are great amount of nested relative and absolute elements at real webpage. Detecting scrollHeight is the only way to make custom-scroller works properly

Comment: var height = 0; $('#parent > div').each(function(){ height = height + $(this).height() }); No?

Comment: I dont know how "я ржал в голос" properly in english. Maybe "I laughed hard" =)

Comment: You can have ANY amount of relative and absolute blocks nested in ANY sequence. Only scrollHeight can detect if some absolute block popped out from the root block